# UIPopover close on selection

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols

Let me first say that I have looked at ALL the stack overflow questions regarding this and none have helped So I thought I'd Start my own.

The Problem: I can't dismiss this popover when selected just like lots of other questions.

The difference: All of their ways haven't worked.

So, Lets look at the code:

In my table view controller.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@protocol PopoverDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)didRowAtIndexPathIsSelected;

@end


@interface tableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) id<PopoverDelegate> myPODelegate;
```

In my table view controller.m:

```
#import "tableViewController.h"

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_myPODelegate didRowAtIndexPathIsSelected];
    NSLog(@"IS it Gone?");
}
```

Then in my Main View Controller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "tableViewController.h"

@interface MainView : UICollectionViewController <PopoverDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) TableViewController *tvController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *tvPopover;
```

And the Main View Controller.m:

```
-(void)didRowAtIndexPathIsSelected
{

    NSLog(@"Dismissing now");
    [tvPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    tvPopover = nil;
}
```

All help is appreciated.

edit:

I've been trying lots of different debuging ideas and tried:

```
NSLog(@"%@", _myPODelegate);
```

Inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath and it came back (null).

Comment: 'tvController. myPODelegate = self' have you set the delegation. Put a breakpoint to check if its calling.

Comment: In the main view controller or the table view?

Comment: in main view controller

Comment: You were right, I just had it in the wrong spot, I needed to put it after I allocated the tvController.  Put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set your delegate in MainView class where you are allocating the object of tvController such that:

> tvController. myPODelegate = self